# Changing an html "for" label with java script

Tags: javascript

I need to change a "for" label from an extension using javascript. I am unsure how to do this.
Thank in advance for the help!

```
<input id="theCheckboxId" type="checkbox" name="theCheckBoxName" />
<label for="theCheckBox">The text I want to change</label>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hMXeR/)

First give the label an id

```
<label id="lbl1" for="theCheckBox">The text I want to change</label>
```

then do

```
document.getElementById("lbl1").setAttribute("for", "theCheckboxId");
```

**EDIT**

Wait, did you want to change the `for` value, or change the actual text of the label?  In any event, here's how you would change the text:

```
if (label.textContent)
    label.textContent = "New Text";
else if (label.innerText)
    label.innerText = "New Text"
else
    label.innerHTML = "New Text";
```

Comment: Another way to change the 'for' value:  document.getElementById("lbl1").htmlFor = "theCheckboxId";

Answer (score 3):

You didn't ask, but if you are using jQuery, you can do it a bit simpler via:

```
$('label[for="theCheckBox"]').text('your new text')
```

That said, the advice of giving it an ID instead is definitely the most performant option, though we don't know if you have access to the HTML or not (as if you did, you could probably just change the text right there)

Answer (score 2):

To change the text, do this:

```
document.getElementById('theCheckboxId').nextElementSibling.textContent = 'newValue';
```

or this:

```
document.querySelector('#theCheckboxId + label').textContent = 'newValue';
```

---

Or if you need to support older browsers, do this:

```
function nextElement( el ) {
    while( (el = el.nextSibling) && el.nodeType !== 1 );
    return el;
}

nextElement( document.getElementById('theCheckboxId') ).innerHTML = 'newValue';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kEYw/

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if he wants to change the text, or the for attribute.  +1 though

Comment: @AdamRackis: Take a quick look at the current text in the example. ;) The title is deceiving I must admit.

Comment: Yes, that was the text that led me to believe he might want to change the text......

Comment: @AdamRackis: Ah, yeah I see now that you had already updated.

Comment: The title and also `I need to change a "for" label` :)

Comment: I was updating as you were posting - don't want you to think I stole your answer ;)

Comment: @AdamRackis: No, I know you didn't. :) Yeah, I've never heard anyone call it a *"for" label*.